# CustomView in ActionBar is being removed when DialogFragment shows in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-dialogfragment

***I am facing issue with custom view in ActionBar on Tablet.***

`I have two fragments added side by side. Left fragment contains a listview and adding the custom view in the ActionBar.`

`Right fragment shows some details. Now when I invoke a DialogFragment, it removes the custom view in the ActionBar.`

Can anybody suggest me the fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. There was some mistake in the DialogFragment which was causing this. I was setting setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false) in DialogFragment.